Unable to split string of urls by delimiter
I have a string similar to the one below:
https://example.com/1.jpg&&&&UAD%@4mQ%iv%7CH;?JD$-p8qD%%Nnf:QX.Vr-B,https://example.com/2.jpg&&&&URCPxDxu4mog^-xuIUjc%Nxvn,Rj%Ot8RiRi,https://example.com/3.jpg&&&&UeF68}_N-=-;%MRjRjofM|M{j[ogxuxuofWA,https://example.com/4.jpg&&&&U|H__P%MRjof_4xuWAof%NoejskCozaeofof,https://example.com/5.jpg&&&&UEE3g_W9D?%Y_IRURj%cNHt6xUaeR%t7j=of

The format of this string is the url to the image + a delimiter (coming from the backend) + image blur hash + optionally repeats.
The expected result:
[
    "https://example.com/1.jpg&&&&UAD%@4mQ%iv%7CH;?JD$-p8qD%%Nnf:QX.Vr-B",
    "https://example.com/2.jpg&&&&URCPxDxu4mog^-xuIUjc%Nxvn,Rj%Ot8RiRi",
    "https://example.com/3.jpg&&&&UeF68}_N-=-;%MRjRjofM|M{j[ogxuxuofWA",
    "https://example.com/4.jpg&&&&U|H__P%MRjof_4xuWAof%NoejskCozaeofof",
    "https://example.com/5.jpg&&&&UEE3g_W9D?%Y_IRURj%cNHt6xUaeR%t7j=of"
]

This seems simple, but I just can't get this working. My final attempt was:
/&&&&.+?(,https)?/ig

The idea is to match anything up until the delimiter ('&&&&') and then an optional comma + https, in the event that there is another url after the current one.
Another approach I tried:
/.+&&&&.+(,https)?/ig

And these two don't quite return what I expect:
/&&&&.+?/ig
https(.+?)&&&&*.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

@nabinsademba this just return one match instead of 5

Can you please tag the language you are using your regex? Different language has different features for regex.

I'm using Javascript

just use "yourstring".split(/,(?=https)/)

Sigh. This is what I was looking for, thanks. If you want to submit an answer, I'll mark it as the accepted one

@JorgeCampos regex with JSON.strignify(result,null,2 ) = perfect ;)

I've added as an answer as requested :)

One way is to match (rather than split) the regular expression https:\/\/.*?(?=https:\/\/|$). Demo. This matches strings beginning 'https://' followed by zero or more characters other than line terminators (.*), as few as possible (.*?), with the last character followed by 'https://' or being at the end of the string.

You can use .split(/,(?=https)/) this is using a positive lookahead to split the string and keep the https portion from the delimiter.


console.log("https://example.com/1.jpg&&&&UAD%@4mQ%iv%7CH;?JD$-p8qD%%Nnf:QX.Vr-B,https://example.com/2.jpg&&&&URCPxDxu4mog^-xuIUjc%Nxvn,Rj%Ot8RiRi,https://example.com/3.jpg&&&&UeF68}_N-=-;%MRjRjofM|M{j[ogxuxuofWA,https://example.com/4.jpg&&&&U|H__P%MRjof_4xuWAof%NoejskCozaeofof,https://example.com/5.jpg&&&&UEE3g_W9D?%Y_IRURj%cNHt6xUaeR%t7j=of"
   .split(/,(?=https)/));



